# How to remove a specific push notification from notifications center Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, push-notification

my App is an app like Uber app, I sent a task to all my drivers this will be by a push notification.

But when a driver accepts the task first I need to remove the sent push notifications from all drivers devices so it won't be show in the notification center.

I search a lot about this issue, but no answers!

anyone try to delete a specific push notification from the notification center after sent it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a silent push-notification that triggers a local notification with a specific identifier.
This identifier should be send inside the silent push notification, that also should carry all information the driver should see in the local notification.
you need two types of push-notifications: show, hide.

got the point?

Comment: There should be a better way now with the new `UserNotifications` framework?